# Deploy build via ftp MsBuild task

Tags: ftp, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildextensionpack

I am trying to automate the ftp upload of a build after local publihsing and file transformation. I've had a look at the http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.7.0/Index.html ftp msbuild task but it only appears to upload files if they are 1 level deep and does not support creating subdirectories. I've searched for ages but cannot find any examples of making it create a tree of directories:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Communication.Ftp TaskAction="UploadFiles" Host="$(FtpHost)" UserName="$(FtpUserName)" UserPassword="$(FtpPassword)" FileNames="@(PublishFiles)" />
```

I cannot use Msdeploy to ftp as I have to build, then transform some files. I understand that the msbuild community tasks were deprecated in lieu of the extension pack (above) so I didn't want to use this. At worst I would consider using a ftp client via CLI but would prefer to use the standard msbuild library if possible.  Is there anyway of enabling me to do this?

Comment: Why do you think the "msbuild community tasks were deprecated " ?  Last activity was 25 days ago.  https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks

Comment: I would gather from what you say, it is not then. I was asking a question because I was trying to understand why there are two and why there was an overlap in functionality and what the relationship eas between them.

Comment: There were just 2 different efforts to fill in some gaps in msbuild functionality.  Microsoft did their thing and somebody else started an open source library.........  Some of them overlap, some have unique functions.  There is no relationship between them, except each library is trying to provide useful and reusable common msbuild routines.  The Microsoft one started small, and has grown over the years.  But I still use the Community one every day.

Answer (score 0):

This task seems to have a recursive tag.

https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Ftp/FtpUploadDirectoryContent.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;

namespace MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Ftp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Uploads a full directory content to a remote directory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>Uploads directory content, including all subdirectories and subdirectory content:
    /// <code><![CDATA[
    /// <Target Name="DeployWebsite">
    /// <FtpUploadDirectoryContent
    /// ServerHost="ftp.myserver.com"
    /// Port="42"
    /// Username="user"
    /// Password="p@ssw0rd"
    /// LocalDirectory="c:\build\mywebsite"
    /// RemoteDirectory="root\www\mywebsite"
    /// Recursive="true"
    /// />
    /// ]]></code>
    /// To go a little step further. If the local directory looked like this:
    /// <code>
    /// [mywebsite]
    /// [images]
    /// 1.gif
    /// 2.gif
    /// 3.gif
    /// [js]
    /// clientscript.js
    /// nofocus.js
    /// [css]
    /// print.css
    /// main.css
    /// index.htm
    /// contact.htm
    /// downloads.htm
    /// </code>
    /// All directories and there content will be uploaded and a excact copy of the content of <c>mywebsite</c> directory will be created remotely.
    /// <remarks>
    /// If <see cref="Recursive"/> is set the <c>false</c>; only index.htm, contact.htm and downloads.htm will be uploaded and no subdirectories will be created remotely.
    /// </remarks>
    /// </example>
    public class FtpUploadDirectoryContent : FtpClientTaskBase
    {
        private String _localDirectory;
        private String _remoteDirectory;
        private bool _recursive;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the local directory that contains the content to upload.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The local directory.</value>
        public String LocalDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return _localDirectory;
            }
            set
            {
                _localDirectory = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the remote directory destination for the local files.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The remote directory.</value>
        public string RemoteDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return _remoteDirectory;
            }
            set
            {
                _remoteDirectory = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the subdirectories of the local directory should be created remotely and the content of these should also be uploaded.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value><c>true</c> if recursive; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
        public bool Recursive
        {
            get
            {
                return _recursive;
            }
            set
            {
                _recursive = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When overridden in a derived class, executes the task.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the task successfully executed; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    Connect();
                    Log.LogMessage( MessageImportance.Low, "Connected to remote host." );
                }
                catch(Exception caught)
                {
                    Log.LogErrorFromException( caught, false );
                    Log.LogError( "Couldn't connect remote machine." );
                    return false;
                }

                try
                {
                    Login();
                    Log.LogMessage( MessageImportance.Low, "Login succeed." );
                }
                catch(Exception caught)
                {
                    Log.LogErrorFromException( caught, false );
                    Log.LogError( "Couldn't login." );
                    return false;
                }

                try
                {
                    if(!DirectoryExists( RemoteDirectory ))
                    {
                        Log.LogError( "Remote directory doesn't exist." );
                        return false;
                    }

                    ChangeWorkingDirectory( RemoteDirectory );
                }
                catch(FtpException caught)
                {
                    Log.LogErrorFromException( caught, false );
                    Log.LogError( "Couldn't change remote working directory." );
                    return false;
                }

                try
                {
                    UploadDirectory( LocalDirectory, "*.*", Recursive );
                }
                catch(FtpException caught)
                {
                    Log.LogErrorFromException( caught, false );
                    Log.LogError( "Couldn't upload directory." );
                    return false;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Close();
            }

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Upload a directory and its file contents.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="localPath">The local path.</param>
        /// <param name="recurse">if set to <c>true</c> all subdurectiries will be included.</param>
        protected void UploadDirectory( String localPath, Boolean recurse )
        {
            UploadDirectory( localPath, "*.*", recurse );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Upload a directory and its file contents.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="localPath">The local path.</param>
        /// <param name="mask">Only upload files that compli to the mask.</param>
        /// <param name="recursive">if set to <c>true</c> all subdurectiries will be included.</param>
        protected void UploadDirectory( String localPath, String mask, Boolean recursive )
        {
            Log.LogMessage( MessageImportance.Low, "Uploading files of local directory {0}.", localPath );


            foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles( localPath, mask ))
            {
                String filename = Path.GetFileName( file );
                Store( file, filename );

                Log.LogMessage( MessageImportance.Low, "{0} uploaded succesfully.", localPath );
            }

            if(recursive)
            {
                foreach(String directory in Directory.GetDirectories( localPath ))
                {
                    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo( directory );
                    bool existsRemotely = DirectoryExists( directoryInfo.Name );

                    if(!existsRemotely)
                    {
                        MakeDirectory( directoryInfo.Name );
                    }

                    ChangeWorkingDirectory( directoryInfo.Name );

                    UploadDirectory( directory, mask, Recursive );

                    CdUp();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a command line tool like ([NCFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/))and use Invoke Process activity from TFS Build workflow to run that command line